# ELI5 - Abduction vs. Inference to Best Explanation (IBE)

Tags: logic

How can one explain, clearly and simply, how abductive reasoning differs from Inference to the Best Explanation (IBE)? I don't understand even though I read [SPE](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/) and these papers:

Campos, Daniel G. *On the Distinction between Peirce’s Abduction and Lipton’s Inference to the Best Explanation* (2011). https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-009-9709-3

Iranzo, Valeriano. *Abduction and Inference to the Best Explanation* (2007)

McAuliffe, William H.B. *How did Abduction Get Confused with Inference to the Best Explanation?* (2015) http://www.psy.miami.edu/ehblab/Abduction%20is%20not%20IBE.%20WB%20McAuliffe.pdf

Walton, Douglas N. *Abductive, presumptive
and plausible arguments* (2001)

Yu, Shiyang, Frank Zenker. *Peirce Knew Why Abduction Isn’t IBE—A
Scheme and Critical Questions for Abductive Argument* (2017)

Comment: I do not know about a 5 year old, but McAuliffe in one place describes the supposed difference very clearly:"*Peirce is associating abduction with hypothesis construction, not with inferring the truth of a hypothesis*". In other words, abduction is not even an inference, it has to do not with criteria for selecting a hypothesis, but with generating it in the first place (responsibility for which Peirce ascribes to "instinct"). However, Peirce also talks about "abductive inference", so I am not sure what is achieved by such hair-splitting. In modern use, the two terms are used interchangeably.

Comment: I was under the impression that Peirce defines abduction as inference to the best explanation. Creating explanatory hypotheses is impossible prior to a logical analysis of what sort of hypothesis is required. So perhaps abduction could be called inference to the best explanation we can create.

Comment: @PeterJ [Inference to the best explanation](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/knowledge/best_explanation.html) is Harman's term from 1965. Even in those passages where Peirce talks about abduction/retroduction as an inference it is, at best, inference to *some* explanation, that predates "logical analysis" and testing. By instinctive response, "*the inquirer is led to regard his conjecture, or hypothesis, with favor.*" Later he separated the creative and the inferential stage and called the former "abduction". "Best" can only be claimed after multiple iterations, long after the abductions.

Comment: @Conifold Yes, but logic is required in order to design an hypothesis that is appropriate and useful, so I cannot see the point in separating the processes. It is only logic that tells us when hypotheses are required and what they need to look like. I take your point about Peirce, but to me the new and the old meaning of abduction are both correct and have to be combined for a complete process. . .   .

Comment: @PeterJ  Logic is neither required, nor useful at the initial stage of discovery/invention. It is more of an intuitive, analogical/metaphorical endeavor, hence "abduction". Appropriate and useful hypotheses do not emerge like Athena out of Zeus's head, although Peirce believed that we have instinctive faculty for hunches with good rate of eventual success. The "complete process" he called logic of discovery and economy of research, and they include many other parts, [deduction, induction, criticism, testing, etc.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce/#dia)

Comment: @Conifold - I understand your point. I just don't have any need for the separation between these functions that is being suggested. We need analysis to determine the sort of 'hunch' we need to have, and logic will determine whether it is a useful one. Logical abduction at its best, as used by Sherlock Holmes, would narrow down our choice of workable hunches to one. Logic would shape our hunches and In philosophy any testing would be by analysis. But I do accept that abduction requires more then just a logical elimination of bad theories.

Answer (score 1):

The William H. B. Mcauliffe article you cite offers an account of the difference that is true to Peirce. But 'abduction' has loosened itself from Peirce's use of the term. I doubt if a single, consistent usage is shared by the five papers you cite, so if you are looking for a single account that squares with all of them then I don't think you'll find it - for the simple reason that it's not to be had.

The relevant extracts from Mcauliffe is the following:

> One of C. S. Peirce’s most misunderstood
> ideas is his notion of abduction, the process
> of generating and selecting hypotheses to
> test. **Contemporary philosophers of science
> have falsely cited Peirce’s idea of abduction
> as a conceptual precursor to the modern
> notion of inference to the best explanation,
> a mode of inference used to decide which of
> competing explanations of a phenomenon
> to regard as true.** ...

> Peirce believed that inquiry involves three
> types of reasoning—abduction, deduction,
> and induction. **While Peirce’s beliefs about
> reasoning, especially abduction, changed
> over time, in his mature work the following picture of reasoning emerges: abduction generates and chooses hypotheses to test; deduction determines the entailments of a hypothesis; induction ascertains whether the evidence
> accords with the hypothesis in question (CP 5.145, 1903).**
> Peirce both
> identified abduction and coined the word.
> His concept of abduction is
> one of the most original contributions he made to the study of reasoning. It is also one of the most poorly understood. Peirce’s concept of
> abduction has been distorted by contemporary philosophers of science,
> who mistakenly claim that it is a conceptual precursor to a kind of
> inference called “inference to the best explanation” (IBE), i.e., an inference to the truth of a hypothesis if it would best explain the given phenomenon.3
> Many philosophers believe IBE is integral to both scientific
> and ordinary reasoning. But Peirce’s idea of abduction is quite different
> from IBE.

> ... **Peirce’s notion of abduction does not
> address how to choose one theory over others given a body of evidence.
> Rather, abduction is best interpreted as a method for arriving at hypotheses and selecting a hypothesis to test. Put another way, inference to the best explanation is supposed to be the last stage of inquiry,
> whereas abduction corresponds to the first stage of inquiry.** (William H. B. Mcauliffe, 'How did Abduction Get Confused with Inference to the Best Explanation?', Transactions of the Charles S. Peirce Society , Vol. 51, No. 3 (Summer 2015), pp.
> 300-319: 300-1.)

Some philosophers of science simply equate 'abduction' with 'IBE'. They are not wrong in this; usage can't be controlled. All I have suggested and argued for is that what Peirce understood by 'abduction' is different from what is generally understood by 'IBE'.

Comment: Not arguing with your answer, which seems correct account of the situation,  but why do we not just include deduction and induction as part of the process of abduction? I cannot see how they can be separated out since 'inference' implies deduction and induction. Is not inventing the best explanation just part of the process of working out what it is?

Comment: @PeterJ. I don't disagree. But for Peirce abduction is a matter of arriving at hypotheses; and as currently advised  IBE is a matter of deciding which hypothesis is the best. These activities are distinct. I see deduction and induction as occurring in both activities. I much appreciate your attention to my answer. Btw: if we cut the link with Peirce, I think quite a few philosophers use 'IBE' and 'abduction' as interchangeable terms. They are not confused; the terms have simply come to mean the same thing. I wouldn't put money on it but I think that's right. However, I wanted to help the OP.

Comment: Thanks. I'd be someone for whom they've come to mean the same thing, but I can see why not everyone agrees.

Comment: @PeterJ. I'm in company with you. I use 'abduction' and 'IBE' interchangeably and I think this is pretty much common philosophical usage. I only drew a distinction between them because the OP asked for an explanation of the difference between abduction and IBE; and if we revert to Peirce's original notion, a distinction can be made. This I set out. I saw no way of reconciling all the sources the OP listed. The OP has not responded to my answer, so I assume s/he is dissatisfied. I might as well delete. Best - G

Comment: Sorry! You deleted this before I read it. I'm not "dissatisfied"! I need some time to grasp all this.

Comment: @Edge. I am sorry - I genuinely thought there was little interest in my answer. I should not have been so hasty. Best - Geoffrey

Comment: @Edge. I restored the answer because, after re-reading it, I revised the presentation. I say this simply to explain myself. Best - Geoffrey

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. Where abduction ends with a *possible* explanation, IBE (allegedly) gives you the *actual* explanation:

**Abduction**

```
 1. E is the case,
 2. and H explains E;
 3. hence, there is a reason to believe H.
```

**IBE**

```
 1. E is the case,
 2. H explains E,
 3. H is the  best explanation for E;
 4. hence, H is true.
```

An additional premise makes all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at this. Let's take it from the bottom up and see what sense we can make of it.

**Deduction**: We can think of deduction in terms of the classical Greek conception of the *syllogism*. Though the point is often lost on people, syllogisms are mainly a teaching tool for the foundations of logic: they show correct (and incorrect) ways of extending the properties of a *category* to individual *members* of that category. If we take the classic example:

```
All Men are mortal  
Socrates is a man  
Socrates is mortal
```

... we can abstract it like so:

```
 Category M has property m
 Object S belongs to category M
 Object S has property m
```

This is merely a systematic way of expressing what we intuitively know: that a property of a group naturally extends to any member of the group. This is the heart of deduction, though generally logical deductions involve more complex chains of property extensions to reach novel, non-intuitive results.

I'll note now, because it will become useful later, that a 'property' in this context means a specific kind of perceivable/measurable event. A 'category' is a collection of individuated but associated objects, things that have (in philosophical parlance) being-in-themselves. A property is something these individuated objects collectively *do* or *have*, not specifically something they *are*. For instance — to break us out of the realm of pure abstract logic — Consider the following syllogism:

```
All objects with mass accelerate according to Newton's formula
Bowling balls are objects with mass
Bowling balls accelerate according to Newton's formula
```

We can all recognize this as the deductive part of a physics experiment. We start with the general theory that all object in the category 'has mass' are subject to the particular, measurable event 'accelerate according to Newton's law'. We pick a particular object that ostensibly belongs to the category and extend the property to that object. Then we have a specific, usable/testable hypothesis.

**Induction**: One of the issues raised by this deductive process is the question of where we get these categories in the first place. In syllogisms (for their pedagogical purposes) we presume *a priori* that the category exists and is well-defined. A premise of the form 'All X' or 'No X' is presented as absolute and all encompassing. But once we step out of that 'teaching' mode it becomes painfully obvious that such 'innate' categories are fuzzy and fluid. We can talk about 'all objects with mass' glibly enough, but it is self-evident that we've never seen 'all objects with mass'. in real-world contexts a phrase of this sort is an assertion that we've seen a *lot* of objects with mass, all those we've seen accelerate according to Newton's laws, and thus we are comfortable justifying our generalized assertion as *a priori* true. This is **induction**: the claim that we have every reason to believe (and no reason to doubt) that our intuited category/property premise is correctly established.

**Abduction**: One of the problems with induction, however, is that we occasionally run across what Thomas Kuhn called an *anomaly*. We observe an event inconsistent with the deductive principle: i.e., object S *appears* to belong to category M but does not conform to property m (Socrates appears to be a man, but for some reason he never dies). Anomalies are sometimes trivial, e.g., when our smart-a$$ed physics professor (and really, what other kind of physics professor is there?) pulls out a feather and shows that it *apparently* does not accelerate the same way as a bowling ball. Those problems come to easy resolution (e.g., grasping the aerodynamic principles involved and retesting the feather in a vacuum chamber clears it up). But other anomalies are much more intractable. They might be objects which *clearly* belong to a category but *stubbornly* persist in aberrant behavior; they might be events without any clear category/object relationship, seemingly appearing out of nowhere.

Now — again, in the Kuhnian model — researchers and scientists have two potential responses to anomalies. On one hand they can (and often do) ignore them. If the sets of inductions and deductions they have established as part of the regular process of science work 99.9% of the time, that is good enough to get a lot of work done. Anomalies might trouble their sleep, but by no means interfere with the day-to-day activity of doing experiments, writing articles, developing technologies, etc. Kuhn called this 'normal science'. But the other response researchers can make to anomalies is to dig in and try to rationalize them: to make them fit into some model. This effort — which Kuhn thought of as fundamental to paradigm shifts in science — is what Pierce was pointing at with the concept of abduction. Abduction involves tearing apart our induced category presumptions, and reimagining category/property relationships: dismantling the things we take as *a priori* true, and then rebuilding the pieces from the ground up.

This is how abduction differs from Inference to the Best Explanation (IBE). IBE exists within the contexts of 'normal' science. Because of incomplete knowledge we might have several different theoretical models that all account for the same non-anomalous data, and then scientists will go through a competitive process of testing to infer *which* of those competing theories works best. Abduction, by contrast, lies outside of the 'normal' practice of science. It is an effort to deal with *abnormal* results, not in competition with other theories but in *opposition* to the established theoretical paradigm. Abduction works at a more primitive level, not just tweaking out the nuances of pre-given category structures, but working out new category/property relationships entirely.

Of course, Pierce predated Kuhn by a good long stretch, so it's a bit touchy to try to read Pierce in Kuhnian terms. But this is the simplest way I can think of to explain it.